# kodi image not picked up in boot

Tags: pi-3, kodi

I have one sd card more than 8 GB, which i was using in a pi3. Want to format the card and copy kodi image in it. Did below steps

> 1. Formatted the SD card using a windows os format feature. (I can see few partitions and formatted all partitions)
> 2. Installed software from https://libreelec.tv/downloads/ and copied kodi image to the SD card.
> 3. Inserted and turned on my pi, nothing happens.
> 4. Only power light blinks, and no green light.
> 5. Based on reading and analysis, it seems sd card is not reading.

How can I format the SD card properly using windows os, to copy kodi image. Can anyone help.

Comment: Exactly which file did you download and how did you 'copy' the downloaded file to the SD card?

Comment: Downloaded using, LibreELEC USB-SD Creator software. Selected pi 2 or 3 from the drop down and downloaded the image suggested by the creator software. I have used one SD which already have noobs, and I formatted it using Windows os. Also I can see 3 partitions in that SD card, will that be an issue?